# ASP.NET MVC Client Model and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I am curious how to handle setting nullable model information on an aspx page to a JavaScript variable. I am using MVC3 RC, and I am sure this is trivial and I am missing something.

Given this code (again, in my aspx view):

```
var myFloat = <%: Model.MyNullableFloat %>;
```

if SelectedAudience is null, what gets written to the page is:

```
var myFloat = ;
```

What I want to get written is:

```
var myFloat = null;
```

Currently, I have some ugly logic:

```
    var myFloat = null;
    <%
        if(Model.MyNullableFloat != null) {
    %>
            myFloat = <%: Model.AdGroup.MyNullableFloat %>;
    <%
        }
    %>
```

Any thoughts on a cleaner way?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a [conditional operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

```
var myFloat = <%: Model.MyNullableFloat.HasValue
    ? Model.MyNullableFloat.Value.ToString() 
    : "null"%>;
```

Remember that both conditions need to return the same type so you'll have to `ToString()` the result if you want to return `"null"`.

Answer (score 1):

```
var myFloat = <%= Model.MyNullableFloat != null ? Model.MyNullableFloat.ToString() : "null" %>;
```

You could also handle this in your Controller

```
Public Class MyModel {
  public string MyNullableFloatAsString { get; set; }
}

Public ActionResult Something () {
  MyModel MyControllerModel;

  MyControllerModel.MyNullableFloatAsString = Model.MyNullableFloat != null ? Model.MyNullableFloat.ToString() + ";" : "null;"

  //Return Model to view
}
```

Now in your View you can simply do this

```
var myFloat = <%= Model.MyNullableFloatAsString %>
```

Comment: don't you have to `ToString()` the nullable float?

Answer (score 1):

Use Ternary operator for a quick solution:

```
var myFloat = <%: Model.MyNullableFloat.HasValue ? Model.MyNullableFloat.Value : "null"  %>;
```

Comment: you'll need to `ToString()` the value otherwise that will throw an exception

Answer (score 1):

It's not much better..!

```
<%= Model.MyNullableFloat.HasValue? Model.MyNullableFloat.ToString() : "null"%>;
```

or you could try an extension method

```
public static string ToStringVerboseNull(this float? myFloat)
{
    return myFloat.HasValue ? myFloat.ToString() : "null";
}
```

and then

```
<%= myFloat.ToStringVerboseNull()%>
```